# javascript year month day calculation differ

Tags: javascript

im having problem to calculate year month day in a same application but different page.

the 1st page display the date as 12Month(s) 5Day(s), while another page showing 1Year(s) 0Month(s) 1Day(s). how can this situation be explain?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(sDate1, sDate2) { //yyyy-MM-dd
        var aDate, oDate1, oDate2, iDays;
        aDate = sDate1.split('-');
        oDate1 = new Date(aDate[0] + '-' + aDate[1] + '-' + aDate[2]);
        aDate = sDate2.split("-");
        oDate2 = new Date(aDate[0] + '-' + aDate[1] + '-' + aDate[2]);
        iDays = parseInt(Math.abs(oDate1 - oDate2) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);

        if (iDays <= 30) {
            alert(iDays);
        } else if (iDays > 30 && iDays <= 365) {
            alert("Duration:" + parseInt((iDays / 30)) + "month(s) " + parseInt((iDays % 30)) + "day(s)")
        } else {
            alert("Duration:" + parseInt((iDays / 365)) + "year(s) " + parseInt(((iDays % 365) / 30)) + "month(s) " + parseInt(((iDays % 365) % 30)) + "day(s)");
        }

        return iDays;
    }  
</script>
```

[My test code](http://jsfiddle.net/h9c8nvp1/28/)

Page1:

```
if (iDays <= 30)
                $("#Display1").html(iDays + " day(s)");
            else if (iDays > 30 && iDays <= 365)
                $("#Display1").html(parseInt(iDays / 30) + " month(s) " + (iDays % 30) + " day(s)");
            else if (iDays > 365)
                $("#Display1").html(parseInt(iDays / 365) + " year(s) " + parseInt((iDays % 365) / 30) + " month(s) " + ((iDays % 365) % 30) + " day(s)");
```

Page2:

```
if (iDays <= 30)
                $("#Display2").html(iDays + " day(s)");
            else if (iDays > 30 && iDays <= 365)
                $("#Display2").html(parseInt(iDays / 30) + " month(s) " + (iDays % 30) + " day(s)");
            else if (iDays > 365)
                $("#Display2").html(parseInt(iDays / 365) + " year(s) " + parseInt((iDays % 365) / 30) + " month(s) " + ((iDays % 365) % 30) + " day(s)");
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the string first on `-` and continue to concatinate them again in the same format?

Comment: can you show the code that is calling the myfunc() on the two pages? you are getting two results so show the inputs

Comment: there wasnt a 4 day gap between page refreshes no?

Comment: Is it a requirement for you to calculate with months that all have 30 days? If not, you should probably calculate the difference between the dates in some other way.

Comment: Update my code above.
@atmd Nope. Same day

It is just a standard for me to do a calculation. im using 1 year = fixed 365days and 1 month = fixed 30days. The issue is why both places use the same code but the result are different which i cannot understand

Comment: Sorry my mistake, maybe I wasnt clear. you have a function called myfunc which takes 2 dates. You have not shown what you are passing into the function on the two pages

Comment: 2 dates are get from DB which stored as 2014-12-01 00:00:00.000 and 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000. I will go check on the value when pass to the function whether it is same like what it is from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee532932%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). I think the problem come from iDays

```
// Set the unit values in milliseconds.
var msecPerMinute = 1000 * 60;
var msecPerHour = msecPerMinute * 60;
var msecPerDay = msecPerHour * 24;

// Set a date and get the milliseconds
var date = new Date('6/15/1990');
var dateMsec = date.getTime();

// Set the date to January 1, at midnight, of the specified year.
date.setMonth(0);
date.setDate(1);
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// Get the difference in milliseconds.
var interval = dateMsec - date.getTime();

// Calculate how many days the interval contains. Subtract that
// many days from the interval to determine the remainder.
var days = Math.floor(interval / msecPerDay );
interval = interval - (days * msecPerDay );

// Calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds.
var hours = Math.floor(interval / msecPerHour );
interval = interval - (hours * msecPerHour );

var minutes = Math.floor(interval / msecPerMinute );
interval = interval - (minutes * msecPerMinute );

var seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000 );

// Display the result.
document.write(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds.");

//Output: 164 days, 23 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds.
```

Try to calculate it with this method for the days

This will look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(sDate1, sDate2) { //yyyy-MM-dd
    var aDate, oDate1, oDate2, iDays;
    // Set the unit values in milliseconds.
    var msecPerMinute = 1000 * 60;
    var msecPerHour = msecPerMinute * 60;
    var msecPerDay = msecPerHour * 24;

    aDate = sDate1.split('-');
    oDate1 = new Date(aDate[0] + '-' + aDate[1] + '-' + aDate[2]);
    aDate = sDate2.split("-");
    oDate2 = new Date(aDate[0] + '-' + aDate[1] + '-' + aDate[2]);
    var interval = oDate2.getTime() - oDate1.getTime();
    iDays =  Math.floor(interval / msecPerDay );
if(iDays <=30){
alert(oDate1);
}else if(iDays>30 && iDays <=365){
alert("Duration:" + parseInt((iDays/30)) + "month(s) " +  parseInt((iDays%30)) + "day(s)")
}else{
alert("Duration:" + parseInt((iDays/365)) + "year(s) " + parseInt(((iDays%365)/30)) + "month(s) " + parseInt(((iDays%365)%30)) + "day(s)");
}
    return iDays;
```

}

Comment: There is another scenario where another guy go to the system and he sees both pages with the exact same date: 12Month(s)5Day(s). which puzzle me more. i Wonder, 1 Year 0 months 1 days is the correct answer or 12month(s)5day(s) is the correct answer.

Comment: You start at 01 december 2014 and stop at 01 december 2015. So the month of december : 31 days, january : 31 days, february : 28 days, march : 31 days, april : 30 days, may : 31 days, juny : 30 days, july : 31 days, august : 31 days, september : 30 days, october : 31 days, november : 30 days. (31 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30) = (31 * 7 + 30 * 4 + 28) = 217 + 120 + 28 = 365 days => 1 year. The problem is iDays%30. With the getDate you will never have problem when you will have 29 days in february.

Comment: With your code you divide 365 / 30 = 12.166, and then 12 * 30 = 360. this get you 1 year and 5 days. And it's wrong, you have just 1 year